# Startswith and endswith domain filter in openerp7

Tags: odoo

I know that the below are supported operators by openerp7.

```
  =, !=, >, >=, <, <=, like, ilike, in, not in, child_of, parent_left, parent_right
```

I would like to implement **startswith** and **endswith** search  in openerp. Ex

```
AB* (starts with AB)
*AB (Ends with AB)
```

Is there a way to do it with the openerp framework itself without executing them as sql statements with cr.execute(). Specifically i would like to do that in global filter.

Updating post for better clarification

[image]

In the above post i have only one customer named ABC Customer. I've searched for Cu% that means starts with Cu whereas the record starts with AB still the result is displayed. In my context it's not okay.

And i do understand that =ilike, % are not meant to place it global filter but on the code (in domain filter). However inorder to make the previous scenario right what should i do?

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 2):

Use `'=like'` and `'=ilike'` operators.

starts with AB is `[('field','=like','AB%')]`

ends with AB is `[('field','=like','%AB')]`

Use `ilike` for case insensitive match.

`like` and `ilike` operators (without '=') automatically add wildcard before and after search value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. how do i use it global filtering. Can you help me with that regard? Thank You for your time.

Comment: you need to modify the partner search view to add a new filter.

Comment: '=like' worked for Odoo10. Thanks